# No sound from Protools Instruments using Xpand!2

Tags: pro-tools

I come from a Cubase background which I don't have anymore and was looking into Protools First.

For starters, all I want to be able to do is create a melody with the piano roll, but there's no audio. I've looked around and have found that if I don't have a midi keyboard I can use the virtual midi keyboard, but after following the instruction, it still doesn't work. The level bars are jumping around, but there's no playback.

Some places advise that after creating an instrument track, I can load up the Xpand!2 synth machine and place the notes, either by pasting them onscreen, or using the virtual midi keyboard... doesn't work.

Others advise that I'd need to paste the notes in to a midi track and link that out into an instrument track loaded with Xpand!2... doesn't work.

I'm willing to accept that it's used by lots of people, so all I can gather is that I must be doing something wrong.

So, does anyone know how I can use Xpand!2 without an external midi keyboard?

Comment: Hi Richard, welcome. Can you please edit your post to be a single question we can focus on, rather than what appears to be just a rant about ProTools at the moment. Their manual and lessons are pretty extensive, and it will do all that you need, despite havingsignificant differences to Cubase (I went through similar issues moving from another DAW to Cubase)

Comment: @RoryAlsop - No, not a rant. People on SE are always asking what you've tried first, which is what I've stated, and there's only a single question that I've asked, "So, does anyone know how I can use Xpand!2 without an external midi keyboard?"

Comment: So that is a very different question to the headline, which suggests no sound from Protools. I have edited to make it appropriate. I have never used Xpand!2 - but I can tell you it isn't needed to get audio out of Protocols.

Comment: Are you getting any other sound from ProTools like audio tracks or even a metronome click? If the level bars are jumping around, I would suggest checking your settings to make sure ProTools can see your audio interface (I'm not a ProTools user - just guessing where the signal might be getting lost)

Comment: @7HzResearch - I haven't tried an audio track yet. I can get the default piano sound to play from the piano roll, but get no sound when adding a Vi (I'm only using Xpand! as an example as that's what comes with it)

Comment: If you're hearing the default piano then that would suggest that it's not the interface. Maybe something to do with routing? Is the audio from Xpand! being sent to the master out? Track along the audio route looking for diversions, mutes or activation requirements. As I said, I'm not a ProTools user so that's about as far as I can help - Good luck and I hope you get it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You should read https://avid.secure.force.com/pkb/articles/en_US/faq/Can-I-use-any-AAX-plug-ins-with-Pro-Tools-First. The free version of Pro-Tools (First) is limited and can’t load most plugins.

Comment: That's not what that article says, and in any case, I'm simply trying to use the Vi that came preloaded with PTF. Thanks though.